# d3 sunburst zoom working in html but not in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I am new to d3, trying to implement d3 Sunburst in my application by referring http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307. The code given in this post works perfectly in HTML even after binding my data.

But When I use the same code in view(mvc.net) chart is rendering but the zoom feature is not working, there is no errors logged in the console.

can someone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: Sorry about that, please check this http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307